# Out of every 100 hostile mobs that spawn during the night, how many on average are enderman?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If 100 mobs spawn during the night, how many of them on average will be endermen?

Comment: I can't find a definitive answer anywhere but I know they spawn in groups of 1 to 4 and the group spawning rate is very low. I'd say from personal experience probably 1 or 2.

Comment: Interesting, neither the article "enderman", nor "spawn" mention anything about them being rarer than other mobs, except for the quote at the top, "its presence is rare in the Overworld". No numbers. Good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enderman are very rare in the Overworld. Most people would agree that 1-2 would be a good estimate, but I conducted an experiment where I would create a random world, wait until nighttime, and count the mobs that spawn.

The results vary:

On the first try, I found 1 enderman and 99 other mobs

On the second try, though, this number had spiked up to 4

On the third try, I got 3 enderman and 97 other mobs

On the fourth, surprisingly, I found 6.

I can't figure out the exact numbers, but the best guess would be that out of 100 mobs that spawn during nighttime, ***3-5 of them*** will be Endermen.

Hope I helped...